# What is the best way to use a two value pair as a key in python?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I am basically attempting to use a matrix in pythons. I have heard about things like a list of lists, but I wasn't sure what the easiest way to manipulate these values would be. I would essentially want there to be a value stored at coordinates (x,y) on a grid, that could only be accessed by having both x and y. Something like:

```
x = 3
y = 4
Matrix[3][4] = value
```

Comment: You can have a look at [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can store a tuple of (x, y) as a key in the dictionary:

```
matrix = {(1, 1): value1, (1, 2): value2, ...}
```

You can retrieve a value associated by a coordinate like follows:

```
value = matrix[(1, 2)]
```